# Deploying Flask application written in one file to Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I've built a flask app and I tread to deploy it on Heroku but I got this error:

```
(venv) MacBook-Pro-alkhas-b-shosha:myApp joodi$ git push heroku master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/<app-name>.git'
```

I think the problem because I  wrote all the application on one file.
This my app structure:

[image]

all Flask code is in `flasker.py`.

So when I start writing on `Procfile` I got confused, I didn't know what I supposed to write on it, here what I wrote

```
web: gunicorn myApp:app
```

What can I do without changing the structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.

### Git issue

> error: src refspec master does not match any.

It looks like you haven't committed any code (Git can't find a `master` branch on your local system). `git push` operates on commits, not files.

Make sure to commit your code locally before trying to push to Heroku.

### `Procfile` issue

Also, update your `Profile` to point to your `flasker.py` file. Assuming your Flask object is called `app`:

```
web: gunicorn flasker:app
```

Comment: Thank you!! Now I think it's deployed as it's said in heroku website and in terminal said `remote: Verifying deploy... done.` but how can I access to my website?

Comment: I tried it and I got this error message `An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served` why?

Comment: @shoseta, that's a runtime error. Check `heroku logs`. If you need help resolving that issue you can ask a new question. Please make sure to include the relevant log output if you do that.

Comment: Actually I'm beginner with git so I'm not sure if what I did correct or not. after I've created `git init` in my folder, I wrote these command `git add -A` and ` git commit` finally this one `git push heroku master`, is that right?

Comment: @shoseta, that should have committed everything in your directory and pushed it to Heroku. That's probably what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message hints to you not being on the master branch.

Try this:

`git push heroku your_branch:master`